# CMakeLists and properties file

Tags: build, cmake

Good day, i searched answer, but not found yet. How to exclude properties from CMakeLists.txt to a separate file? Like it in gradle we have file gradle.properties where we can set paths etc. What is the best practices or official way?

Comment: If you are looking a way to **affect** on the project building, then CMake *cache variables* is what you need. If you want to **import** target with its properties from one project to another, look into CMake *project importiing* facilities.

Comment: I want separete properties file. CMakeLists.txt shoudn't be changed to build on separete machines

Comment: You may change cache variable without modifying `CMakeLists.txt`, this is primary intention of that variables. See e.g. [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html) for `set` command, part describing `Variable types in CMake`.